# Something I am stuck in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to write down the Fourier series for \$x(t)=1\$ for \$|t|\leq 1\$ and zero otherwise (which is expanded periodically to other intervals with this period of 1), and compare it graphically with \$x(t)\$, for different values for \$N\$, where \$x(t)=\sum_{-N}^{N} a_k e^{ j k\Omega_0 t}\$.

Here's the code I wrote, basically the interval should be between -2 and 2, but I get all the time an error, I hope someone can correct me or find a better way to do this.

```
n=linspace(-2,2,5);

x=abs(n)<=1;

y=symsum(exp(-1i*k*pi/4)*(sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi))*exp(1i*k*pi*n/2),k,-1,1);

y2=symsum(exp(-1i*k*pi/4)*(sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi))*exp(1i*k*pi*n/2),k,-3,3);

y3=symsum(exp(-1i*k*pi/4)*(sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi))*exp(1i*k*pi*n/2),k,-7,7);

y4=symsum(exp(-1i*k*pi/4)*(sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi))*exp(1i*k*pi*n/2),k,-19,19);

y5=symsum(exp(-1i*k*pi/4)*(sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi))*exp(1i*k*pi*n/2),k,-79,79);
```

---

I get the following error:

`??? Undefined function or variable 'k'. Error in ==> AS at 3 y=symsum(exp(-1i*k*pi/4)*(sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi))*exp(1i*k*pi*n/2),k,-1,1);`

Comment: Just throwing this out there, what error are you getting?

Comment: I get the next error: <code>??? Undefined function or variable 'k'.

Error in ==> AS at 3
y=symsum(exp(-1i*k*pi/4)*(sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi))*exp(1i*k*pi*n/2),k,-1,1);</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add syms k; at the beginning
- sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi) should be sin(k*pi/4)/(k*pi+eps) to avoid division
  by zero.
- legned should be legend
- you can't place 5 subplots in a 2x2 figure

Comment: I might as well use sinc function instead of sin(x)/x. Forgot to look for such a function in matlab